# weird key press issue with html select

Tags: html, select

We have a dropdown(html select) which contains number from 00 to 59 (possible value for minutes). When control is on focus and user input 13 (or 24 or 59 etc) using key board, it selects the number 13 (or 24 or 59 etc) in the control. Which is expected behavior.

But when user input number like 44 it selects 40 then 41. Same is the issue with 22,33,55.

This is the behavior with Firefox, Chrome, Safari. Interestingly in IE9 it is working fine(you input 44 it selects 44)

Please suggest how to make the behavior of "html select" uniform in all the browser. Preferably the way it is working in IE9, which seems correct.

Example code:

```
<html>
<body>
Select Minutes: 
    <select id="hr_sel_min">
        <option title="00" value="00" selected="selected">00</option>
        <option title="01" value="01">01</option>
        <option title="02" value="02">02</option>
        <option title="03" value="03">03</option>
        <option title="04" value="04">04</option>
        <option title="05" value="05">05</option>
        <option title="06" value="06">06</option>
        <option title="07" value="07">07</option>
        <option title="08" value="08">08</option>
        <option title="09" value="09">09</option>
        <option title="10" value="10">10</option>
        <option title="11" value="11">11</option>
        <option title="12" value="12">12</option>
        <option title="13" value="13">13</option>
        <option title="14" value="14">14</option>
        <option title="15" value="15">15</option>
        <option title="16" value="16">16</option>
        <option title="17" value="17">17</option>
        <option title="18" value="18">18</option>
        <option title="19" value="19">19</option>
        <option title="20" value="20">20</option>
        <option title="21" value="21">21</option>
        <option title="22" value="22">22</option>
        <option title="23" value="23">23</option>
        <option title="24" value="24">24</option>
        <option title="25" value="25">25</option>
        <option title="26" value="26">26</option>
        <option title="27" value="27">27</option>
        <option title="28" value="28">28</option>
        <option title="29" value="29">29</option>
        <option title="30" value="30">30</option>
        <option title="31" value="31">31</option>
        <option title="32" value="32">32</option>
        <option title="33" value="33">33</option>
        <option title="34" value="34">34</option>
        <option title="35" value="35">35</option>
        <option title="36" value="36">36</option>
        <option title="37" value="37">37</option>
        <option title="38" value="38">38</option>
        <option title="39" value="39">39</option>
        <option title="40" value="40">40</option>
        <option title="41" value="41">41</option>
        <option title="42" value="42">42</option>
        <option title="43" value="43">43</option>
        <option title="44" value="44">44</option>
        <option title="45" value="45">45</option>
        <option title="46" value="46">46</option>
        <option title="47" value="47">47</option>
        <option title="48" value="48">48</option>
        <option title="49" value="49">49</option>
        <option title="50" value="50">50</option>
        <option title="51" value="51">51</option>
        <option title="52" value="52">52</option>
        <option title="53" value="53">53</option>
        <option title="54" value="54">54</option>
        <option title="55" value="55">55</option>
        <option title="56" value="56">56</option>
        <option title="57" value="57">57</option>
        <option title="58" value="58">58</option>
        <option title="59" value="59">59</option>
    </select> &nbsp;minutes
</body>

</html>
```

Please find the example code in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2QTvJ/

(open the example in IE9 and chrome to see the difference.)

Comment: The behavior is browser-dependent and more complicated that described in the question. E.g., on Firefox, if you type 13 fast enough, 13 is selected; slower, and first 10 gets selected, then 30. A control like this is a usability nightmare (most users don’t know they can type in a select box anyway), so using a two-character text input box is better.

Comment: We are planning to leave it as it is, saying its browser related and any way it wouldn't create a huge difference. But still I would like to know how other are handling this issue?

Comment: This is not an issue, this is how browser works. If you press 5 and wait and press 5 again, it takes you from 50 to 51, 52, 53 and so on. So its how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Raheel was saying, it goes up to the next value starting with the character that you hit, 4 or 5, for example. You could have a text box input that then changes the drop down value or some other type of form element that would distinguish the value.

Another way would be to distinguish value with jquery keypress function.

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/